# MultiResourceItemReader finish processing file event

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

How can I know when a step has finish to process (processor used) all the row from a file ? (MultiResourceItemReader = multiple files)

I made this:

```
@CommonsLog
public class MultiResourceItemReaderWrapper<T> extends MultiResourceItemReader<T> {

    private List<URI> processedResources = new ArrayList<URI>();

    @Override
    public void setResources(Resource[] resources) {
        super.setResources(resources);
        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            log.info("Resource found to be read: " + resource);
            try {
                processedResources.add(resource.getURI());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterStep
    public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("MultiResourceItemReaderWrapper.processedResources", processedResources);
    }

}
```

And in a future step, I would like to archive this files (move/rename).

I don't know if is the best way. But with this method, I don't know if a file has been processed without errors (I want to archive files that are processed without errors only) ?

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ResourceAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ResourceAware.html) interface in your domain object; reading will set current resource name into read item and you can check for file change.

Comment: Instead of URI in my example ?

Comment: don't use a custom reader but use standard one and store processed resources when check for resource change.

Comment: Ok, but how and where do you store them ? Do you have an example ?

Comment: into execution-context as well as you did in your example.

Comment: Ok but how to access to `StepExecution` outside a managed bean (I use annotation method `@AfterStep` in this case with my custom class) ? In a `@Bean` annotated method, StepExecution is not injected during bean instanciation.

Comment: change you domain object as described in my answer; into processor check for resource change (or errors, using exception handler) and store (or don't store) URI into step-execution or any other bean. step execution is preferrable due to restartability and possibility to move across step. with that info you can reach your goals.

Comment: OK but multiple domain object can have same resource (how process them). And I always don't know how to access it (read resource).

Comment: Use different processors for different domain object and interface cited in answer to access resource. Thats all.